# android proguard, skip jars

Tags: android, proguard

I want to know if it is possible to skip jars in proguard so that it don't obfuscate them... I am trying to do that with this comand: -libraryjars myjar.jar  but I keep having problems with my code..

I am trying to export a project that has javamail api for android and the project is supposed to retreive my exchange emails using imaps protocol...

I am using a trust manager to  pass the certificate validation (because I have self signed certificate on my exc server). If I compile and run the app without exporting it, everything works fine. If I export the app I am getting the invalid certificate error.

In my activity I pass the SSLSocketFactory (the one that skips the cert validation) on a Property object :

```
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "mail.utils.DummySSLSocketFactory");
```

So I think the problem could be somewhere in the javamail jar but I don't know how to let all classes from the jar to be skipped by proguard...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a general ProGuard configuration, specifying -libraryjars would be the preferred solution indeed.

In the Android build script, jars in the libs directory are already added automatically as -injars, which makes this less convenient. You can still specify to preserve all code though, e.g. all public classes, fields, and methods in the library:

```
-keep public class mail.** {
  public *;
}
```

You may be able to refine the configuration by only keeping relevant classes, e.g.

```
-keep class mail.imaps.socketFactory
-keep class mail.utils.DummySSLSocketFactory
...
```

Without knowing the internal implementation of the library, this refinement will probably require some experimentation.

Comment: so if I have a package named mail and inside a packet named com.sun.activation.registres, I can do : -keep public class mail.** {
  public *;
}
 and That packet will be skiped by proguard? Thanks!

Comment: I also noticed that this mail.jar has inside the javax.activation package and this package is also in the jre library. My project has jre library imported, is there a way that I could specify the jar archive from where to skip the package ?