# How to get ProGuards -libraryjars with filter working in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, proguard

My build.gradle file contains the following dependency:

```
compile files('../libs/ddogleg-0.8.jar')
```

The app is perfectly working with ProGuard disabled. After enabling ProGuard, a lot of warnings like the following break the build:

```
Warning: org.ddogleg.solver.impl.WrapRealRootsSturm: can't find referenced class org.ejml.data.Complex64F
```

According to the ProGuard docs at http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass , this issue should be fixed using a `-libraryjars` filter like the following:

```
-libraryjars ../libs/ddogleg-0.8.jar(!org/ddogleg/solver/impl/WrapRealRootsSturm.class)
```

The problem is, even if the filter is specified, ProGuard keeps happily complaining that it can't find the referenced class.
Now, if `-dontwarn org.ddogleg.solver.impl.WrapRealRootsSturm` is used instead of a `-libraryjars` filter, it's working. Hence at least I know that I'm editing the right file...

It's kinda obvious that I'm doing it wrong. Do you have any ideas how to get the -libraryjars filter working?
Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your proguard config:

```
-keep class org.ejml.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.ejml.**
-keep class org.ddogleg.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.ddogleg.**
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is there also a way to solve it using libraryjars filters?

Comment: This is a safer approach. Check similar problem reported earlier [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5412338/1957401)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. So the -libraryjars filter ain't working because the jars are added automatically as -injars?

Comment: that's what the answer says in the other similar post i linked to. I've not tried so cant say for sure.

Comment: K, thank you for the clarification. I'll use -dontwarn then.